# Android app crashes when minifyEnabled is true

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am using a multi-module app and the app crashes when `minifyEnabled true` in the `installed` module's build.gradle.

Following is the deobfuscated stacktrace I retrieved from play console.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: com.packagename, PID: 16978
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.packagename.login.Utils.AuthenticationActions.saveCredentials(AuthenticationActions.java)
    at com.packagename.login.LoginActivity$1$1.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java)
    at com.packagename.login.LoginActivity$1$1.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$EmitterTransform$1.onCompleted(IonRequestBuilder.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:166)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:77)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:8)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Tap.java:18)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:3)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:22)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:96)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I am unable to understand what does this code correspond to `'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)'`

I am using multiple external libraries, one of which is *ion koush*.

I have tried adding this to ever proguard-rules.pro file in my project
`-keep class com.koushikdutta.** { *;}`. But this didn't yield any success.

Comment: Are you using some kind of JSON to POJO library? It may fail to transform them if POJO properties are changing name because minify. Keep those pojos in proguard-rules.

Comment: You are a life save @LeoPelozo. I added `-keep class com.packagename.**.data_models.** {*; }` in every module's proguard-rules.pro and it is now working. Please do post your answer with a short explanation. I'll accept it. Many thank. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens when your app transform json to POJOs and you have minify enable. Minify change those POJOs making the transformation impossible (it will compile, but all your POJOs propierties will be null).

Keep those POJOs adding `-keep class com.packagename.<path to pojos> {*; }` to your proguard-rules file.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Brother. I have search a lot for days to find out the exact reason for the crash on minifying with the solution

Answer (score 5):

Also add "@Keep" above class name to all Pojo files.

Comment: Bishwajeet Singh - Could you mention @Keep import package line?