# Picasso doesn't load imageView from url

Tags: android, gradle, picasso

I am looking to reduce the size of my APK for performance issues. That's why I introduced this into my `app.gradle` :

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

However, I realize that some images loaded with picasso from a URL are no longer displayed.

I realize that some of my objects have null values when this was not the case before using `MinifyEnable: true`

Comment: did you check the user permissions ?

Comment: i think my problem is related to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850552/app-crashes-when-minifyenabled-is-true-logcat-included

Comment: if its about minify, check proper proguard on Picasso documentation https://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Facing the same issue. @ZachBvy, Did you find any solution?

Comment: yes my problem was actually not related to picasso but to my pojos which were minified

Comment: adding this line `-keep class <package.name.of.your.pojos>.**` in my progard-rules.pro solved my problem